# Python (for Revit Dynamo): unexpected token in while loop iteration

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, revit-api

I'm a Python noobie trying to find my way around using it for Dynamo. I've had quite a bit of success using simple while loops/nested ifs to neaten my Dynamo scripts; however, I've been stumped by this recent error.

I'm attempting to pull in lists of data (flow rates from pipe fittings) and then output the maximum flow rate of each fitting by comparing the indices of each list (a cross fitting would have 4 flow rates in Revit, I'm comparing each pipe inlet/outlet flow rate and calculating the maximum for sizing purposes). For some reason, adding lists in the while loop and iterating the indices gives me the "unexpected token" error which I presume is related to "i += 1" according to online debuggers.

I've been using this while loop code format for a bit now and it has always worked for non-listed related iterations. Can anyone give me some guidance here?

Thank you in advance!

**Error in Dynamo:**

```
Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript 
operation failed. 
unexpected token 'i'
```

**Code used:**

```
import sys
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

dataEnteringNode = IN

a = IN[0]
b = IN[1]
c = IN[2]
d = IN[3]

start = 0
end = 3
i = start
y=[]

while i < end:
    y.append(max( (a[i], b[i], c[i] ))
    i += 1

OUT = y
```

Comment: Three left parenthesis, two right ones. The Python interpreter just tells the truth.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Solved! You've got sharp eyes.

Comment: Yep, I read the error messages.